# Creating a project builder and plugin in Gradle

Tags: plugins, gradle

I want to use Gradle to create following things.

I want to create a plug-in which can

1. Create a project structure
2. project life cycle of my one like plugin 'java' has many java related lifecycle like i need my own lifecycle
3. Internally jars or zips my project
4. runs my project.

How to implement all these.. any example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most of what you are asking for is information provided in the cookbook: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook

to create a project structure read: mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-gradle-for-mixed-java-and-groovy.html
and look for the initProject task.

Comment: I tried to run the task but i am getting this error
<pre><code>
:create-dirs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Temp\gradle\build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':create-dirs'.
Cause: No such property: sourceSets for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention

* Try:
Run with -s or -d option to get more details. Run with -S option to get the full (very verbose) stacktrace.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.062 secs

</code></pre>